# Change html to other div onClick (dynamic gallery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onclick, gallery

I've searched allover for quit long time before posting a new question.
I have two DIVs forming a dynamic photo gallery, one DIV loads thumnails images from database, and the other DIV displays fullsize image of the clicked thumbnail.

Simplified code :

```
    <div id="thumbs_div" onclick="document.getElementById('full_div').innerHTML ='<img src="images/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>"/>';"><img src="thumbs/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>" /></div>
```

As you know I can't use innerHTML with html tags. and I'm stacked with it..
I know that it's possible with jQuery, but I don't know how.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With an HTML/PHP file of:

```
<div id="thumbs_div">
    <img src="thumbs/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>" />
</div>
```

Use this as a script:

```
$('#thumbs_div').click(function(){
    $('#full_div').html('<img src="images/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

without jquery

```
<script>
function onImageClick()
{
document.getElementById('full_div').innerHTML ='<img src="images/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>"/>';
}
</script>

<div id="thumbs_div" onclick="onImageClick()"/>';"><img src="thumbs/<?php echo $row_some_recordset['photo_name']; ?>" /></div>
```

Hope that helps